# RegExp extract specific string followed by any number with leading / trailing whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, string-matching

I want to extract a string from another using JavaScript / RegExp.
Here is what I got:

```
var string = "wp-button wp-image-45 wp-label";
string.match(/(?:(?:.*)?\s+)?(wp-image-([0-9]+))(:?\s(?:.*)?)?/);
// returnes: ["wp-button ", "wp-image-45", "45", undefined]
```

I just want to have "wp-image-45", so:

- (Optional) any character
- (Optional) followed by whitespace
- (Required) followed by "wp-image-"
- (Required) followed by any number
- (Optional) followed by whitespacy
- (Optional) followed by any character

What is missing here? Is it just some kind of bracketing or more?
I also tried

```
string.match(/(?:(?:.*)?\s+)?(?=(wp-image-([0-9]+)))(?=(:?\s(?:.*)?)?)/)
```

**Edit:** In the end I just want to have the number. But I'd also make this step in between.

Comment: [\d]+ will find just the number, if your input string is always formatted as you show.

Comment: @Mogsdad: Putting a character class shortcut in a character class is a bit redundant. Just `\d+` (no square brackets) will do.

Comment: True... I'd been playing with Julian's regex in an on-line tester, and didn't reduce far enough. Still, you did the same in your answer, what's your excuse?! ;^)

Comment: @Mogsdad: I put it in a capturing group (parenthesis, not square brackets) so that he could make use of the number without further parsing, that's not the same thing ;)

Comment: @Blixt d'oh! Ok, that's a good reason, which I should have recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regexps are not required to start matching at the beginning of the string, so your attempts to match whitespace and any character aren't necessary. Also, "any character" includes whitespace (except newlines in certain modes).

This should be all you need:

```
string.match(/\bwp-image-(\d+)\b/)
```

This will capture, for example, "wp-image-123" into matching group 0, and "123" into matching group 1.

`\b` means "word boundary", which ensures that you won't match "abcwp-image-123def". A word boundary is defined as any place where a non-word character is followed by a word character, or vice versa. A word character is consists of a letter, a number or an underscore.

Also, I used `\d` instead of `[0-9]` simply out of convenience. They have slightly different meaning (`\d` also matches characters considered numbers in other languages), but that won't make a difference in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If all of that surrounding stuff is optional and all you want is the number then there's no point to matching for any of that stuff except for that "wp-image-" prefix, just do:

```
var string = "wp-button wp-image-45 wp-label";
string.match(/wp-image-([0-9]+)/);
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding word boundaries (or use lookaround) to avoid cases such as "wwwp-image-45abc" matching.